# How to process message in order with spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

Does the spring integration framework have any features I can use to guarantee message order?

We are needing to run our spring integration flow on two different nodes to keep up with the message volume.  I have seen several solutions for solving this issue, but I wanted to see if the framework already has something.

This article might better explain what I'm trying to ask.

http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2010/02/message-ordering-in-jms-using-coherence.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is here. And its name [Resequencer](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Resequencer.html).
From Spring Integration Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#resequencer.

Each of message for reordering has to have a `correlationId` header to compare with other messages and `sequenceNumber` to determine the real order of that message to emit.

The `release-partial-sequences="true"` does the stuff to release messages, when the correct order is achieved by default `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` on the next message.

Comment: Do you know of any examples using the resequencer?

Comment: Not sure what you need else in addition to Docs, but here is a test-case (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/aggregator/integration/ResequencerIntegrationTests.java) and its `ResequencerIntegrationTests-context.xml`

Comment: Would it be possible to use a timestamp instead of an sequence number?

Comment: No, only `sequenceNumber` is supported for `resequencer`

Comment: Do you think that maybe using jmsxgroupid and jmsxgroupseq might be a better way of keeping messages in order?  We definitely want to have multiple consumer reading the messages of the queue.

Comment: You can have several consumers, but you need to use `resequencer` anyway. And if the several consumers might send their messages to that, you might need to use persistence MessageStore for resequencer. JMS  doesn't provide such an option to reorder messages with the same `correlationId`